# SQL Query from table using condition from another table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to make a query on my SQL table using conditions from another table but I'm struggling at it.

**Here's my problem:** 
I have 2 tables called Bookings and Transaction.

Booking Table

- Booking ID (Not really related here)
- TransactionID

Transaction Table

- TransactionID
- TransactionDate

**What I want to do:**

I need to find the total number of bookings made within one week.

For example, I need to get all booking rows in the **Bookings Table** where **TransactionDate** is within 7 days old.

**What I think I want:**

```
int weeklyTotalBookings = ((from bk in context.Bookings where 
bk.TransactionDate <= DateTime.Today && bk.TransactionDate >= weekStartDate 
select resHotel).ToList()).Count;
```

Except that this wouldn't work because TransactionDate is not inside Bookings table.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select b.*
from bookings b join
     transactions t
     on b.TransactionID = t.TransactionID
where t.TransactionDate >= dateadd(day, -7, getdate());
```

(Presumably, `TransactionDate` is always in the past so you don't need to check for future dates.)